# Changing multiple variables using other variables Python

Tags: python-3.x

My question is about Python variables. I have a bunch of variables such as p1, p2 and p3. If I wanted to make a loop that let me change all of them at once, how would I do that? Here is what I got so far.

```
p1 = 0
p2 = 0
p3 = 0
p4 = 0
p5 = 0
p6 = 0
p7 = 0
p8 = 0
p9 = 0
p10 = 0



x = 10

while(x < 0):
    p+str(x) = p+str(x) + 1
    x - 1
```

This code should change 10 variables called p1, p2, p3 (ect) by 1 each.

Comment: One common pattern is to instead have a list `p`, instead of individual variables, and store your values such that `p2 == p[2]`. Then just iterate over that list.

Comment: In this case, I can only use variables. Unfortunately, I cannot use lists, arrays, objects or dictionaries.

Comment: @CODERKID why ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Because it is for pygame, but I didnt want to involve Pygame because then nobody would look at this question.

Comment: And how does pygame prevents you from using a list ? Also, if you hope to get any _serious_ answer (not hacks from copy-paste 'coders') you'd rather explain your real problem (search for "xy problem" if you want to know why).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a number to a variable like that, instead you might want to use a Object, array or a dictionary. What you are trying to do, can be done in a dictionary really easily. The code below shows how you can implement your code with dictionary.

```
dictionary = {} # it can hold P1 P2 p3...
x = 10
while(x < 0):
    dictionary["p" + str(x)] = dictionary["p" + str(x)] + 1
    x - 1
```

You may want to research more about this subject as this is just a quick example of how to use a dictionary in python

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> p1=0
>>> p2=0
>>> p3=0
>>> x=3
>>> while(x>0):
        exec("%s%d += 1"%("p",x))
        x = x -1

>>> p1
1
>>> p2
1
>>> p3
1
```

Although this does the job. Don't follow this approach(really bad way), instead look for alternative like using lists or dicts.